# Problems with gazebo plugin tutorials

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am now doing the gazebo plugin tutorial and came across some difficulties doing rosmake. My cpp file is

```
#include "gazebo.hh"
#include "physics/physics.h" 
#include "common/Events.hh" 
#include "common/Plugin.hh" 
#include "common/Time.hh" 
#include "common/common.h"


namespace gazebo
{
  class PluginTemplate : public Plugin
  {
    public: PluginTemplate() : Plugin() 
            {
            }
    
    public: void Load( sdf::ElementPtr &_sdf )
            {
            };

    
  };
   
  GZ_REGISTER_PLUGIN(PluginTemplate)
   
}
```

However, I got the following error while running rosmake

```
"home/chengxiang/gazebo_tutorials/src/simple_world_plugin.cpp:26:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘}’ token"
```

the "}" in question here is the last "}"

Could any kind soul please enlighten me on how to solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43320/problems-with-gazebo-plugin-tutorials/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-09-07**:
Thanks Lorenz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry, [the tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro) was broken, I have just corrected the error.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-09-07**:
Thanks hsu! I will try it out.